# Подсчет количества уникальных значений

Tags: sql

Надо посчитать из какой страны пришло больше всего заказов, первые 5 стран.

БД: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

Запросом

```
 SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, c.Country, o.CustomerID FROM Customers c
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID=o.CustomerID
    ORDER BY c.Country
```

получаю таблицу

```
Австрия 
Австрия 
Австрия 
Бельгия 
Бельгия
```

Не могу понять как сделать

```
Австрия 3
Бельгия 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью оператора **GROUP BY** вы группируете результаты выборки по столбцу **c.Country**, а агрегатная функция **COUNT** выводит количество строк каждой группы.

```
SELECT c.Country, COUNT(*)
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY c.Country
```

Comment: Спасибо. Итоговый вид запроса:

  SELECT c.Country, COUNT(*) as var
    FROM Customers c
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    GROUP BY c.Country
    ORDER BY var Desc LIMIT 5